# react-scripts-ts not using --max-old-space-size

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript

I have an old `react-scripts-ts` project. In that project I am using `node v16.14.0`, `react v16.12.0`, and `typescript v3.7.5`.

My problem is setting `NODE_OPTIONS=--max_old_space_size=8192` takes effect but ignored by `nodeJs`. This causes out of heap memory errors on file changes on my react app. Here is my v8 heap data before npm start:

```
> v8.getHeapStatistics()
{
  total_heap_size: 6750208,
  total_heap_size_executable: 524288,
  total_physical_size: 6750208,
  total_available_size: 8635152728,
  used_heap_size: 4956808,
  heap_size_limit: 8640266240,
  malloced_memory: 254064,
  peak_malloced_memory: 614560,
  does_zap_garbage: 0,
  number_of_native_contexts: 2,
  number_of_detached_contexts: 0
}
```

Here is the one after file change that cause auto compile and nodeJs crash:

```
> v8.getHeapStatistics()
{
  total_heap_size: 6750208,
  total_heap_size_executable: 524288,
  total_physical_size: 6750208,
  total_available_size: 8635063368,
  used_heap_size: 5046168,
  heap_size_limit: 8640266240,
  malloced_memory: 254064,
  peak_malloced_memory: 614560,
  does_zap_garbage: 0,
  number_of_native_contexts: 2,
  number_of_detached_contexts: 0
}
```

and here is the `nodeJs` error in `npm start`:

```
<--- Last few GCs --->

[10256:00000221E939B840]   197654 ms: Mark-
sweep 2038.5 (2090.4) -> 2030.3 (2090.4) MB
, 825.5 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.141, curr
ent mu = 0.031) allocation failure scavenge
 might not succeed
[10256:00000221E939B840]   198503 ms: Mark-
sweep 2038.3 (2090.4) -> 2030.5 (2090.6) MB
, 826.2 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.087, curr
ent mu = 0.027) allocation failure scavenge
 might not succeed


<--- JS stacktrace --->

FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near
 heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript
heap out of memory
 1: 00007FF6D4667B7F v8::internal::CodeObje
ctRegistry::~CodeObjectRegistry+114079
 2: 00007FF6D45F4546 DSA_meth_get_flags+655
42
 3: 00007FF6D45F53FD node::OnFatalError+301
 4: 00007FF6D4F2B29E v8::Isolate::ReportExt
ernalAllocationLimitReached+94
 5: 00007FF6D4F1587D v8::SharedArrayBuffer:
:Externalize+781
 6: 00007FF6D4DB8C4C v8::internal::Heap::Ep
hemeronKeyWriteBarrierFromCode+1468
 7: 00007FF6D4DC58F9 v8::internal::Heap::Pu
blishPendingAllocations+1129
 8: 00007FF6D4DC28CA v8::internal::Heap::Pa
geFlagsAreConsistent+2842
 9: 00007FF6D4DB5529 v8::internal::Heap::Co
llectGarbage+2137
10: 00007FF6D4DB36E0 v8::internal::Heap::Al
locateExternalBackingStore+2000
11: 00007FF6D4DD8266 v8::internal::Factory:
:NewFillerObject+214
12: 00007FF6D4B0A735 v8::internal::DateCach
e::Weekday+1797
13: 00007FF6D4FB8F91 v8::internal::SetupIso
lateDelegate::SetupHeap+494417
14: 00000221EB51BDE1
```

BTW: I am using windows 10.

Thanks.

Comment: `heap_size_limit: 8640266240` indicates your `max_old_space_size=8192` takes effect and is NOT ignored by node.

Comment: so why i am getting heap out of memory error? @hackape

Comment: One possible reason, esp. when you run node in VM or docker, is that your `max_old_space_size` is set larger than or too close to physical/virtual RAM upper bound.

Comment: Way-too-large setting fools garbage collector to think it’s not hitting memory limit yet, so it doesn’t kick when in reality running out of memory.

Comment: I have 16GB of memory in my system. Before running my application, I have 10GB of ram free so I think that this configuration  is possible and not larger than RAM upper bound.

Comment: That sounds alright. So my guess is wrong. Sorry I don’t know the reason.